# Working out equation of motion from potential energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, potential-energy

A potential energy of a particle in 2 dimensions $x$ and $y$ is given by
$$V = \dfrac{k(x^2+y^2)}{2}$$

And the equations of motions for this particle are to be calculated given that the mass of the particle is $m$.

I used $F_x = -dV/dx$ and $F_y = -dV/dy$ and got

\begin{align}
m\ddot x =& -kx \\
m\ddot y =& -ky \, .
\end{align}

Defining $\omega^2 = k/m$

\begin{align}
\ddot x +\omega^2 x =& 0 \\
\ddot y +\omega^2 y =& 0 \, .
\end{align}

Solving the differential equations I get

\begin{align}
x =& Ae^{-i \omega t} + Be^{i \omega t} \\
y =& Ce^{-i \omega t} + De^{i \omega t}
\end{align}

which could be re written as
\begin{align}
x =& a \cos(\omega t) \\
y =& b \cos(\omega t) \, .
\end{align}

To write this in vector form I can just consider $x$ and $y$ to be the components of the vector so

$$\vec r(t) = a \cos(\omega t) + b \cos(\omega t) \, .$$

The answer however is
$$\vec r(t) = \vec c_1 \cos(\omega t) + \vec c_2 \sin(\omega t) \, .$$

Why are $c1$ and $c2$ considered vectors?

Could this equation have been written like this:
$$\vec r(t) = \vec c_1 \sin(\omega t) + \vec c_2 \cos(\omega t) \, ?$$

I ask because if yes, then I can change my equation to be
$$\vec r(t) = a \cos(\omega t) + b \sin(\omega t) \, .$$

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69417/discussion-on-question-by-mohammad-areeb-siddiqui-working-out-equation-of-motion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equations:

$$\begin{align}
x =& a \cos(\omega t) \\
y =& b \cos(\omega t) \, .
\end{align}$$

should be:

$$\begin{align}
\vec x =& a \cos(\omega t) \hat x \\
\vec y =& b \cos(\omega t) \hat y
\end{align}$$

because $\vec x$ and $\vec y$ are the vectors giving the displacement in the $x$ and $y$ directions. $\hat x$ and $\hat y$ are the unit vectors in the $x$ and $y$ directions. Then the total displacement is:

$$ \vec r = \vec x + \vec y $$

One more point to note is that you have oversimplified your solution. A more general solution is:

$$\begin{align}
\vec x =& (a \cos(\omega t) + b \sin(\omega t)) \hat x \\
\vec y =& (c \cos(\omega t) + d \sin(\omega t)) \hat y
\end{align}$$

You would get the values of $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ from the initial conditions i.e. the position and the velocity of your system at $t=0$.

Comment: Thanks alot!! I had been stuck on this for a very long time!

Comment: Also, isn't $\vec x = (a \cos(\omega t - \theta ) + b \sin(\omega t - \theta )) \hat x$ more general?